# Import local modules in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, module, jupyter-notebook, package

I would like to outsource some general functions useful for multiple notebooks in a module (also for testing purposes). The current directory structure looks like the following

```
jupyter/
├─ notebooks/
│  ├─ 01 Notebook 1.ipynb
│  ├─ ...
├─ src/
│  ├─ module_a/
│  │  ├─ __init__.py
│  │  ├─ func_a.py
│  ├─ module_b/...
├─ tests/...
├─ data/...
├─ .../
```

In `func_a.py`, there is a simple function `def print_a(): print('a')`

However, when I would like to import and use `module_a` in `01 Notebook 1.ipynb` by using (what I think makes sense)

```
from .. src.module_a import print_a
```

I got an `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`. What am I doing wrong? I am using Python 3.9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try to [append the src directory to the system path](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470982/how-to-add-a-python-module-to-syspath) like so:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/your/src")

from src.module_a import a
```

please note that you can use the relative path from your notebook root and not absolute path like in the example above, so the following:

```
sys.path.append("src")
```

should work too

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But isn't that a terrible hack and antipattern to change the sys path?

Comment: the sys path will not be changed permanently (if you remove the `sys.path.append` it wont work even after youve ran it), i dont know if it's considered a "hack" i think it is a legitimate way

Comment: to add to my first comment, the use of the sys path is only happening in the notebook which is for demonstration purposes & not as a core component of your project